# Kafka Lag Monitoring System

Tags: apache-kafka, yahoo-kafka-manager, kafka-burrow

I've researched the Kafka monitoring systems and found out that there are two types of them.
First is consuming __consumer_offsets topic and Second is using kafka api.

It seems using kafka broker api is much more accurate, if cluster has many consumers - which means producing lots of __consumer_offsets, creating lag for consuming them and shows totally inaccurate lag monitoring.
The only disadvantage seems sending api intervally can be burdensome to broker, but it looks very slight.

I have no idea why the most famous lag monitoring systems like burrow, kafka manager use this inaccurate method.

Comment: What is your question? Remember, "Why" questions usually tend to get closed because they are mostly answered opinion-based.

Comment: Also, questions seeking recommendations for tools are similarly opinion based - [help], but polling the "api" would not be the most accurate because there's a delay... Consuming the offsets topic doesn't cause any more problems than consuming any other topic, and will be more real-time. AFAIK, CMAK doesn't poll the offsets topic